# Генерация графика Google Chart без перезагрузки по данным массивов PHP

Tags: php, ajax, google-chart

Добрый день. Я задавал похожий вопрос но плохо раскрыл детали и поэтому подсказки не помогли. Поэтому еще раз обращаюсь за помощью:

Есть код php который по полученным данным с фронта и б/д генерирует таблицу приблизительно такого вида:

Банк   Переплата Сравнить

Банк1    2000    checkbox

Банк2    3000    checkbox

Банк3    4000    checkbox

*****   ******   *******

БанкN    15000   checkbox

Одновременно код генерирует массивы, которые содержат переплату по каждому банку разбитую по месяцам (в реальности при построении таблицы поле переплата заполняется последним значением каждого из этого массива).

Что хочу сделать:

После выбора любых двух банков через checkbox без перезагрузки страницы создать график посредством Google Chart. График строится на основе массивов соответствующих выбранным банкам т.е. две линии показывающие по месяцам переплаты по данным банкам. Также в график нужно подтянуть названия выбранных банков, но названия можно зашить в массив последним элементом.

Генерация действия по выбору двух любых банков будет такая:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
var checked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
if (checked == 2) {
 ---- действие ------
}
});
```

Судя по уже полученным подсказкам нужно действовать через ajax т.е. нужно выцепить нужные массивы и передать их на другой файл где сгенерировать график и как то вернуть его на страницу. Но как php массивы передать в JS? и как вернуть назад js график?

А сдругой стороны, возможно есть способ без передачи данных на сервер но при этом не вызывая перезагрузку страницы?

Прошу подсказки как действовать.

Comment: Т.е. данные для построения нового графика есть на странице уже при первой ее загрузке?

Comment: @br3t да, массивы уже созданы.

Comment: Тогда в вашем `действие` создаете новый график вместо старого на основании обновленных данных.

Comment: @br3t :), но как это сделать без обновления страницы? и кроме того, как выцепить и передать в js массивы активных checkbox